# REST api response 407 error

Tags: python, rest, authentication, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to implement REST api via python requests module.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
proxies = {'http': 'http://username for proxy:password for proxy@proxyhost:proxyport'}
response = requests.get('http://restapi host:restapi port/service', proxies=proxies, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username for rest api', 'password for rest api'))
print response
```

**Response:**

print response : Response 407 error

print response.text : Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request http://rest api host:rest api port/service from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.

I have given proxy authentication and credentials but it still responds with proxy authentication is needed. How to solve this issue?

Comment: As the provider of the API. Without any knowledge of the service we can not help.

Comment: I am trying to implement Opennebula OneFlow service REST api. Is this what you have asked?